# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 35

Tags: android, json, gson

I freshly started with gson and i am trying to parse a JSON string which starts as an object and always get the same error 
JSON

```
{
  "code": 200, 
  "data": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "emailSender": "dsfd@mail.ru", 
        "countryCode": null, 
        "emailSenderReply": null, 
        "rejectedReason": null, 
        "messageReplySenderMessageDeleted": null, 
        "lastNameReceiver": null, 
        "wpMessagesRatingReplyId": null, 
        "wpMessagesRatingRating": null, 
        "countryMemberId": 143, 
        "phoneSenderReply": null, 
        "messageReplyReceiverMessageDeleted": null, 
        "readStatus": "unread", 
        "phoneReceiverReply": null, 
        "membersSenderUid": "m8692031", 
        "wpMessagesRequestTitle": "Fazzzzzz", 
        "title": "Fazzzzzz", 
        "countryTitle": null, 
        "emailReceiver": null, 
        "firstNameReceiverReply": null, 
        "id": 1288, 
        "messageReplyId": null, 
        "membersReceiverUid": "m1000002", 
        "time": "2014-12-28 14:32:09", 
        "wpMessagesRequestCategoryId": 4, 
        "lastNameReceiverReply": null, 
        "lastNameSender": "dsad", 
        "phoneReceiver": null, 
        "status": "unanswered", 
        "messageReplyReceiver": null, 
        "messageReplyStatus": null, 
        "memberReceiverRole": "admin", 
        "isConsultant": 1, 
        "roleReplyReceiver": null, 
        "wpMesssagesRequestCategoriesSystemName": "orders", 
        "lastNameSenderReply": null, 
        "memberSenderRole": "member", 
        "wpMesssagesRequestCategoriesName": "Orders", 
        "requestMessage": 1101, 
        "wpMessagesRequestPriority": "middle", 
        "messageReplyTime": null, 
        "message": "OLOLO", 
        "wpMessagesRequestCountryId": null, 
        "sender": 4481, 
        "firstNameReceiver": null, 
        "messageReplyMessage": null, 
        "firstNameSender": "asdas", 
        "firstNameSenderReply": null, 
        "emailReceiverReply": null, 
        "roleReplySender": null, 
        "messageReplySender": null, 
        "wpMessagesRequestProductId": null, 
        "receiver": 4364, 
        "isMessageForwarded": 0, 
        "wpMessagesRequestStatus": "not-taken", 
        "phoneSender": "2(342)-4-23-42", 
        "wpMessagesRequestMessage": "OLOLO"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I keep running into the error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 12
```

The error in my log points to this line:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Main main=gson.fromJson(a, Main.class);
```

Here is my pojo

```
static class Main{
        int code;
        boolean error;
        List<Data> data;
    }
    static class Data{
        Enteties messages;
    }
    static class Enteties{
        String msg_title;
        String msg_time;
        int msg_id;
        String msg_status;
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return msg_title+" "+msg_time+" "+msg_id+" "+msg_status;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Main class has Data as a list.  Your JSON has it as an object.  The types need to match.  If you expect only 1 data in main, do not use a list.  If you expect 1 or more datas, make the code that generates the data send down an array (even if that array only has 1 object in it).

Comment: i changed , now i get null instead of values

Comment: thank you sir,your answer helped a lot  ,null values were because of pojo names misconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

your POJOs should look something like this

your Entity class:

```
public class Entity {
    private int id;

    private String emailSender;
    private String membersSenderUid;
    private String title;
    private String time;

    @SerializedName("wpMessagesRequestStatus")
    private String status;

    // getters, setters & toString methods
}
```

**@SerializedName** is an annotation that indicates this member should be serialized to JSON with the provided name value as its field name. For more details [check here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Your Data class:

```
public class Data {
    private List<Entity> messages;

    // getters, setters & toString methods
}
```

And finally Main class:

```
public class Main {
    private int code;
    private boolean error;
    private Data data;

    // getters, setters & toString methods
}
```

Here goes the parsing code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Main main=gson.fromJson(jsonData, Main.class); // here jsonData is the string that is holding your actual json data
System.out.println(main);
```